# JSP Error Pages

Tags: java, jsp

Is there a way to have a custom error page while maintaining the HTTP error code (not capturing the error with an error page that itself has a 200 code)?  Can that have to be done using the  in web.xml or can I do that directly in the JSP?

If I send an HTTP error code using response.sendError then no other text appears on the page.  I am able to get text on the page using out.println() but it doesn't seem to be able to print out html, just basic text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use response.setStatus(int statusCode) to set the status to 404 while still allowing you to send your custom error page.

Comment: Thanks. Now I can get an HTML page with an HTTP error without redirecting to a separate error page.

Answer (score 2):

Yes in your web.xml you can configure error codes with the 'error-page' tag and child elements of 'error-code' and 'location'

```
<error-page>
   <error-code>400</error-code>
   <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/errorpages/errorPage400.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```