# spring mvc and jsp pages location under webapp vs WEB-INF

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I have question on spring mvc and jsp pages location under webapp vs under WEB-INF.

Lets say we have below setup.

```
webapp
  WEB-INF
    mvc-dispatcher.xml
    web.xml
  login.jsp
  register.jsp
  success.jsp
  error.jsp
  index.jsp
```

I can refer to pages from browser using urls like http://host.com/app/index.jsp and from there I can link (a href) to *register.jsp*.  From *register.jsp* I post to controller which can return *success* view that resolves to *success.jsp* (using *InternalResourceViewResolver*).

If I move jsp pages under *WEB-INF* (instead of earlier under *webapp*) I will be unable to refer http://host.com/app/index.jsp from browser.  Also from *success.jsp* currently I link to *index.jsp* using a href="index.jsp" which will need to change to map to controller (may be at / like the dispatcher servlet) that would return *index* as view name.  So all my links will need to be served by controller.  am I right ? or is there a way to refer to jsp pages without any mapped controller when jsp pages are located under WEB-INF (given InternalResourceViewResolver is configured).

Regards,

Miten.

Answer (score 6):

You are absolutely right. You cannot refer to JSPs inside `WEB-INF` directly from browser. And this is **very good**. All you requests should be forwarded to JSP via controller, and all your JSP should be under `WEB-INF`. There are many reasons to do so:

- Users cannot get actual source of you JSPs, and it positively impacts on security.
- Many JSPs rely on some request attributes to exist (The Model). When user calls JSPs directly from browser, the Model is not present. This may break some logic.
- One JSP under `WEB-INF` may be used to serve different URLs without any changes, and users will know nothing about it!
- It's just a good practice, when you do MVC ([Model 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_2), not [Model 1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_1))

Considering you question about direct referring to JSPs without Controller:

- You can directly map HTTP exceptions / Throwables to JSPs via [JSP error pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10323653/jsp-error-pages). A simple technique is good for custom 404, for example.
- When using Apache Tiles + Spring and accessing some `/notmappedurl` Spring (Tiles) will try to find `notmappedurl` template definition. (From my experience with Tiles + Spring). I think other view technologies have similar behavior.
- It is not very difficult to write: `@RequestMapping("/someurl")void someurl(){}`. Spring will try to find `someurl` view, based on method name. Just a stub.

Comment: seems I will need a consolidated controller mapped to / with more specific RequestMappings at method level to handle all jsps mappings so then I can refer to them in a href as /someurl as per your example.  I agree with benefits of doing so but was trying to see if I can get by for certain cases where content is more static but still in jsp just to keep them together in same folder. - Miten.